# Ruby reading value return from MS Sql Sproc

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am a newbie in Ruby. I am executing a stored procedure in MS Sql server 2008 Enterprise Edition which is returning a value using a return statement e.g.

```
 IF Exist(select ID from table  where PKID = param)
return 1
else
return 0
```

I want to know in Ruby either a stored procedure's call returned 1 or 0. 
There is a counter way  i.e.

```
IF Exist(select ID from table  where PKID = param)
Selecct 1
else
Select 0
```

I don't want to adopt the above mentioned way because I have pre-existing many stored procedures returning values using return statement.

```
begin
     @gw_connection = ConnectionManager.new(@app_config["gwdb"])
     result = @gw_connection.execute_sproc(sql)
     puts"Called successfully"
     p result
     rescue => e
       puts "An error occured, details : #{e.message}"
     ensure
       @gw_connection.connection.close  
     end
```

result is **nill**

Comment: This ConnectionManager is some class you wrote or it's a ruby class?

Comment: its my class inherited by ActiveRecord::Base rockskull

Comment: And this `execute_sproc` ? Is a custom method? Can you post it's code, if it is?